# Quick way to divide matrix entries K_ij by K_ii*K_jj in Python

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

In Python, I have a matrix **K** of dimensions (N x N). I want to normalize **K** by dividing every entry K_ij by sqrt(K_(i,i)*K_(j,j)). What is a fast way to achieve this in Python without iterating through every entry?

My current solution is:

```py
import numpy as np
K = np.random.rand(3,3)
diag = np.diag(K)
for i in range(np.shape(K)[0]):
    for j in range(np.shape(K)[1]):
        K[i,j] = K[i,j]/np.sqrt(diag[i]*diag[j])
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post your code.

Comment: You could pretty easily compose a (NxM) matrix that has the correct normalization value at each (i, j), and then just use element-wise divide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you have to iterate through every entry, at least internally.  For square matrices:

```
K / np.sqrt(np.einsum('ii,jj->ij', K, K))
```

If the matrix is not square, you first have to define what should replace the "missing" values `K[i,i]` where `i > j` etc.

Alternative: use [`numba`](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/5minguide.html?highlight=njit) to leave your loop as is, get free speedup, and even avoid intermediate allocation:

```
@njit
def normalize(K):
    M = np.empty_like(K)
    m, n = K.shape
    for i in range(m):
        Kii = K[i,i]
        for j in range(n):
            Kjj = K[j,j]
            M[i,j] = K[i,j] / np.sqrt(Kii * Kjj)
    return M
```

Comment: Maybe it would be also good to add `@njit(error_model="numpy") to avoid the costly division by zero check.